# Moving DotNetNuke From Local To Host

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have installed DotNetNuke 5.6 on my local drive,now i want to move it to host to run web site. What steps should I do to run my web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't done anything to the site on your localhost, it might be easiest to have your host install a clean copy of DotNetNuke to a site for you. Many hosts will do that for you or provide automated tools to install it through their control panel.

In order to help you move a DotNetNuke site, we really need more details in order to provide a complete answer (your hosting company should be able to give you guidance) but the basics are:

```
1a. If you are just using SQL Express on the local host and plan to
use it under SQL Express on the host as well, you'll just need to
FTP up the DB files along with all the other files. 
1b. If you'll be
running the DB under a full SQL Server: Backup your database on your
localhost, copy the DB backup to your host, and restore the database
to the database server provided by the host.
2. Create a blank website on the host.
3. FTP all site files from your localhost to the root directory of your new website. 
4. Make sure the Network Service account has Full Access permissions to the root directory and all sub-directories.
5. If you're using a full SQL Server, you'll need to update connection strings in the web.config to point to the restored DB and
ensure you're using a user/login with read/write rights to the DB.
6. Browse to the site.
```

That should do it.

Comment: thanks,i did this works,i just wanna know,how should i change web.config file to point to restored db?

Comment: in the web.config, Look for SiteSqlServer and update the connection string. You just need to know the DB server name, database name, username, and password.